# How can I redirect traffic to an Host machine port from a VM inside in a CentOS Docker container?

Tags: centos, iptables, docker

I have this scenario:

- a HOST machine running Debian with ufw installed.
- a CentOS docker container that have an VM that working on an specific IP.
- This VM have an app working on the container calling `https://app.domain` as put an entry in `hosts` file (**APP_IP**).

I want calling `localhost:7000` on my HOST machine and use the VM app that is in the container.

I already exposed the port  of the container while running it with `-p 7000:7000`.

I read about `iptables` and I tried to redirect the traffic on the container, but without success!

If this is the way... can anyone make an example of `iptables` command that I should run?

---

**EDIT:** Following [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/572934/how-do-i-update-linux-host-iptables-rules-to-redirect-traffic-within-a-docker-co) I tried:

```
IP_CONTAINER=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
APP_IP=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING --protocol tcp --destination $APP_IP --dport 80 --source $IP_CONTAINER --jump DNAT --to-destination $APP_IP
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

but still without success!

Comment: I'm not following what you're trying to do.  If you want a port on the host that will forward to a port in the container, the `-p` option you used should have done that.

Comment: It's not only the port as the container app that I would use outside the container work on a proper IP.

Comment: Are you contacting 127.0.0.0:8080 ?  You shouldn't need the IP forwarding or `iptables` rule.

Comment: sorry, maybe I was not clear enough! The app is inside a VM in the CentOS docker container. For that expose only the port isn't enough. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I was able to connect to the app**, inside the VM that is inside the CentOS Docker container, from Host **using a proxy properly configured in the CentOS container** that forward traffic from the container's exposed IP to VM ip and app port!

So the way is... a **proxy** inside the container!

I used **HAProxy** with this configuration for `haproxy.conf`:

```
global
log 127.0.0.1 local0
debug

defaults
log global
mode http
timeout connect 5000
timeout check 5000
timeout client 30000
timeout server 30000

frontend apps
bind CONTAINER_IP:80
bind CONTAINER_IP:443
option tcplog
mode tcp
default_backend apps

backend apps
mode tcp
balance roundrobin
option ssl-hello-chk
server webserver1 APP_IP:APP_PORT check

frontend api
bind CONTAINER_IP:6443
option tcplog
mode tcp
default_backend api

backend api
mode tcp
balance roundrobin
option ssl-hello-chk
server webserver1 APP_IP:APP_PORT check
```

and I have **enabled forwarding** for the container:

```
$ sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1
$ sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 1):

To redirect traffic from your HOST machine port to the app running on the VM inside the CentOS Docker container, you need to configure the Docker container network and use iptables rules to forward the traffic.

Here's an example of the steps you can take:

1. Create a Docker network and attach the CentOS container to it:

   ```
   docker network create mynetwork
   docker run --network=mynetwork --name=centos_container centos
   ```
2. Inside the CentOS container, configure the VM to use a static IP address in the same network as the Docker network. For example, if the Docker network IP range is `172.18.0.0/16`, you can configure the VM to use `172.18.0.2`.
3. Expose the port of the VM inside the CentOS container to the Docker network. For example, if the app is running on port 80 inside the VM, you can use the docker run command with the `-p` option to map the port to the Docker network:

   ```
   docker run --network=mynetwork --name=centos_container -p 7000:80 centos
   ```

   This will map the container port 80 to the host machine port 7000.
4. Enable IP forwarding on the HOST machine:

   ```
   echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
   ```
5. Configure `iptables` rules to forward the traffic from the HOST machine port 7000 to the VM inside the Docker container. For example, if the IP address of the VM inside the container is `172.18.0.2`, you can use the following `iptables` rules:

   ```
   iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 7000 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.18.0.2:80
   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
   ```

   These rules will forward incoming traffic to port 7000 on the HOST machine to port 80 on the VM inside the container, and rewrite the source IP address to the IP address of the HOST machine.

After following these steps, you should be able to access the app running on the VM inside the CentOS container by visiting http://localhost:7000 on your HOST machine.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check current `iptables` rules

   ```
   iptables -t nat -L -n -v
   ```
2. Enable IP forwarding

   ```
   echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
   cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
   ```
3. Rules to forward PG traffic

   ```
   iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination new-master-ip:80
   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
   ```
4. Check `iptables` rules

   ```
   iptables -t nat -L -n -v
   ```